# Windsor constructor injection possible for class with constructor parameters?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, constructor-injection

```
public interface ISomething
{
    string SomeMethod(string arg);
}


public class Something : ISomething
{
    public Something(Type type)
    {
        // initialization using type argument
    }

    public Something(string name)
    {
        // initialization using name argument
    }

    public string SomeMethod(string arg)
    {   
        // do something
    }
}       


public class SomethingElse : ISomethingElse
{
    public SomethingElse(ISomething something)
    {
        // ....
    }
}         


public class WindsorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<ISomething>().ImplementedBy<Something>().Named("Something").LifestyleSingleton());
    }
}
```

( For brevity I'm leaving out the standard Windsor initialization code. )

But when an instance of `ISomethingElse` is created ( perhaps due to `ISomethingElse` being injected in some other class ),  Windsor can't resolve the `ISomething` constructor parameter because it doesn't know what to supply for the type argument.

```
Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException was unhandled by user code
  HelpLink=groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Can't create component 'Something' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

'Something' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'System.Type' which was not registered.
- Parameter 'name' which was not provided. Did you forget to set the dependency?
```

Comment: Do you know which Type to use as a parameter when calling the `WindsorInstaller`?

Comment: I do know the Type, but the problem is that ISomething, Something, and their WindsorInstaller are actually in a separate project which is built as a NuGet package and subscribed to by the project that uses SomethingElse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Inline-dependencies&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1),  this shows how to add dependencies which are not services (thus cannot be resolved by the container)

Comment: Thanks that's very good info. However, in my case the component and its registration is contained in a NuGet package. In my consuming project, is it possible to re-register the component supplying the dynamic parameter ?

Comment: Just realized I can explicitly perform the registration in the consuming project so this is now solved.